# Missing Cloud Storage Feature in Project

Tags: google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-storage

I have an existing project in [Google Clouds](https://cloud.google.com/console) that only showing this 3 features: App Engine, BigQuery, and Cloud Datastore. The project is not accessible from Google APIs Console (not showing in the dropdown). How can I add Google Cloud Storage to this project?

*If I create a new project now in either [Google Clouds](https://cloud.google.com/console) or [Google APIs](https://code.google.com/apis/console), it will come with App Engine, Compute Engine, Cloud Storage, BigQuery, APIs, Cloud Datastore, and Cloud SQL. But I want to use back my existing project because it has whitelisted to use gaeforphp.

Thanks.

Comment: It doesn't show up in the [Google APIs console](https://code.google.com/apis/console) dropdown? That seems bad. The currently-selected project does not show up in the dropdown but is instead the bolded text at the top of the dropdown. Is it possible it's already selected?

Comment: The bolded project is another of my project, which also having some other problem (it has App Engine but it doesn't appear in https://appengine.google.com/). To be clear, if I click at the drop down, select Other Project -> Open, I can only see 1 project which is the bolded project.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

App Engine projects created in the past may not be connected to the rest of the Google Cloud APIs. You can enable this by:

- visiting: https://appengine.google.com/
- Choose Application Settings from the administration section on the left.
- Scroll to the very bottom, the Cloud Integration section.
- Click the add project button.

Comment: that works! Thanks a lot! btw, do you also have any idea about the other of my project that appears in Google Cloud Console and Google APIs Console but not in AppEngine? Thanks again~!

Comment: That sounds like the opposite situation. Unfortunately, I don't know of a way to add an App Engine project to an existing APIs Console project.

Comment: To add an App Engine project to an existing APIs Console project: Go to https://cloud.google.com/console#/project/YOUR_PROJECT/teams, add the App Engine gservice account email there.